# Advantages/Disadvantages of separating DOM hosting and Logical API

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

So, I can now say that I'm more than just a beginner developer, I've been working as a junior developer full time for over a year now, with my main focus being on Laravel, and I like it.

I have also learned about Angular.js and absolutely love it.

I have an idea, but I'm not sure if it's very practical. And asking questions that end in opinionated answers is frowned upon, so I'll try to keep this as factual as possible.

I'm considering developing two separate Laravel applications. One that would host the DOM HTML and JavaScript for my Angular application, and another that would interact with it via Json with an API key that would be responsible for interacting with the database and the logistical analysis of the data.

What would be some security concerns with doing this over a standard Laravel/Bootstrap application? Is there a good potential for an increase in performance as I suspect? What are some of the other Advantages/Disadvantages I probably haven't considered yet?

Comment: Afraid your question is off topic, as it's really broad as well as still mostly asking for opinions. You need a colleague, developer friend, or other kind of peer for this type of question. Stack Overflow isn't well suited for this type of question I'm afraid.

Comment: Yea, I kind of figured. I only have one colleague, and no developer friends. Haha. More or less hoping someone else has either done this or thought of it, some information they may have to share. Also, I've been using this site for several years and still don't have any reputation because I haven't asked enough questions to answer anything yet... :P

Comment: Why would you even need a server side framework to deliver static html files in the first place?

Comment: Actually I just thought of that too. lol. I could just use plain html/js. still early for me. ;P no coffee yet. Well, on second thought, it would be nice to have a Templating system, but Laravel may be overkill. perhaps something a bit more lightweight. I'll look into that.

Comment: angular includes a templating system

Comment: Ah, right. I suppose it would. I hadn't got that far into it. Perhaps that's where I should start reading...